# carregar div com ajax sem erro nas respostas

Tags: php, ajax, api

estou com um problema com meu script ajax, a função dele é pegar o cep digitado e trazer os valores dele via API , porem ele esta apresentando um erro que nao consigo resolver, ao digitar o cep completo ele mostra exatamente as informações mas elas desaparecem em seguida! então como estou utilizando o método .keyup, ao apertar qualquer botão, as informações voltam a aparecer na tela e ai sim elas ficam fixas, quando o cep esta incompleto ou errado, ele me mostra a mensagem "nada encontrado" e quando o cep esta correto, ele retorna os valores do cep, mas como citei a cima, ao digitar o cep inteiro, ele mostra todas as informações e em uma fração de segundos, volta a mensagem "nada encontrado", entao ao apertar qualquer tecla, volta a mostrar os dados e finalmente fica fixo.

ja modifiquei o codigo varias vezes e nao consegui descobrir o erro, testando com o html e o ajax da o erro, testando com o arquivo php, nao da nada errado, entao creio que seja meu codigo ajax

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".cep").keyup(function(){


    var cep = $(".cep").val();
    console.log(cep);



            $.ajax({
                url: "content/plugin/cep/cep.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {cep: cep},
                cache: false,

                success: function(res){

                    if(res.codigo == "1"){  

                    $('.bairro').html('');
                    $('.bairro').html(res.resposta);
                    console.log(res.resposta);
                    return false;
                    }else if(res.codigo == "0"){

                    $('.bairro').html(res.resposta);

                    }
                }

            });

    });


});


cep.php

<?php 

function busca_cep($cep){
    $resultado = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep='.urlencode($cep).'&formato=query_string');

    parse_str($resultado, $retorno); 
    return $retorno;
}


$ceps = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cep']);
$resultado_busca = busca_cep($ceps);


$log   = $resultado_busca['tipo_logradouro'];
$logr  = $resultado_busca['logradouro'];     
$bai   = $resultado_busca['bairro'];         
$cid   = $resultado_busca['cidade'];         
$uf    = $resultado_busca['uf'];         


if($uf == null){
    $retorno2['codigo'] = 0;
$retorno2['resposta'] = "<div class='fimcep'>Nada encontrado</div>"; 

                         header('Content-type: application/json');
                         echo json_encode($retorno2);
                         return false;
}else{
    $retorno2['codigo'] = 1;
$retorno2['resposta'] = "<div class='fimcep'>$log $logr $bai $cid $uf</div>"; 

                         header('Content-type: application/json');
                         echo json_encode($retorno2);
                         return false;
   }
?>
```

Comment: voce está rodando fora de um servidor quando faz o teste só em Ajax?

Comment: rodei so o arquivo php e retornou certo os dados, mas quando junto com o ajax e o html, da esse bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal sera você usar a função `blur()` do `jquery` para realizar o ajax.
A função do `keyup()` é de observar cada mudança do input, ou seja, cada tecla digitada, sendo assim seu ajax esta fazendo uma request cada vez que o usuário digita uma letra.

A função `blur()` é ativada apenas quando o usuário seleciona "outro campo" para preencher, ou seja, quando ele já terminou aquele campo em que estava, sendo assim, a requisição ajax só acontecera uma vez que é quando ele terminar de digitar.

Você também pode verificar a quantidade de caracteres no `input` antes de fazer a requisição ajax;

```
$('.input').keyup(function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    // 8 é a quantidade de caracteres minima de um cep
    if (length >= 8) {
        // ... a requisição ajax
    }
});
```

## [Veja funcionando no JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71shsgtk/1/)

Comment: intendo man, porem nao existe outro campo a ser preenchido ate a resposta retornar, tem apenas 1 campo 'cep' , quando este campo retorna ok, ai libera os outros campos, do contrario, todos os outros campos ficam desativados, tem como eu colocar o blur() ser ativado somente quando o input estiver com determinado numero de caracteres?

Comment: eu tambem poderia colocar um botao com a função click() mas e que eu gostaria de deixar o mais dinamico possivel, bem botoes

Comment: eu tambem poderia tirar o keyup() e colocar algum tipo de contador de caracteres, por exemplo, se campo .cep tiver 8 caracteres, ai ele ativa o ajax, e assim eu acho que pode aparar de dar erro, pq ira fazer apenas uma consulta, mas eu nao tenho ideia como fazer essa função, estou pesquisando agora

Comment: @JonnysJ. o `blur` vai funcionar quando o usuário trocar o foco do input; se ele clicar fora (não necessariamente em outro input) vai ativar, se der tab e etc, fiz uma alteração conforme seu comentario.

Comment: eu testei com o blur e deu certo! entao realmente o problema e com o keyup, mas ainda sim eu precisava de outro metodo sem click, pq o blur so funciona se eu preencher a caixa e clicar em qualquer outro lugar, diferente do keyup que preenche a caixa automaticamente, se tiver que clicar, e melhor colocar um botao para facilitar o entendimento para o usuario.

Comment: @JonnysJ. você pode usar o keyup como no exemplo que coloquei.

Answer (score 0):

bom pessoal, graças a o @Rafael Acioly, ele me deu uma ideia de ativar o ajax somente quando o campo cep for totalmente preenchido, bom fiz uma pequena alteração no codigo e finalizei da seguinte forma, a função php de buscar o cep so é ativada se o campo cep tiver exatamente 9 digitos ( contando com o '-' que separa os numeros ) do contrario, nao faz nada, o ajax envia sempre as informações mas o php barra ate ter exatamente oque ele precisa, isso ajudou ate pq se o usuario apagar algum numero do cep, ele bloqueia os campos ate o usuario preencher os campos de novo, e o usuário também pode mudar o cep sem dar nenhum erro no formulario. bom nao sei se no brasil temos ceps fora do padrao 99999-999, se tivermos, meu codigo nao vai funcionar :(

segundo esse site [Padrao CEP Brasileiro](https://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/precisa-de-ajuda/o-que-e-cep-e-por-que-usa-lo/estrutura-do-cep), meu codigo vai funcionar!

irei postar o codigo para o pessoal que precisar

```
cepajax.js

$("document").ready(function(){



$(".cep").keyup(function(){

    var leg = $(this).val().length;
    console.log(leg);

    $('.bairro').html('Procurando');
    var cep = $(".cep").val();
    console.log(cep);



            $.ajax({
                url: "content/plugin/cep/cep.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {cep: cep, leg: leg},
                cache: false,

                success: function(res){

                    if(res.codigo == "1"){  


                    $('.bairro').html(res.resposta);
                    console.log(res.resposta);
                    $('.msg_input').addClass('disableding');
                    return false;
                    }else if(res.codigo == "0"){

                    $('.bairro').html(res.resposta);
                    $('.msg_input').removeClass('disableding');
                    return false;
                    }
                }

            });





});
```

});

cep.php

```
<?php
```

function busca_cep($cep){
    $resultado = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep='.urlencode($cep).'&formato=query_string');

```
parse_str($resultado, $retorno); 
return $retorno;
```

}

$leg = $_POST['leg'];
$ceps = $_POST['cep'];

if ($leg == 9 ){

```
$resultado_busca = busca_cep($ceps);
```

$log   = $resultado_busca['tipo_logradouro'];
$logr  = $resultado_busca['logradouro'];
$bai   = $resultado_busca['bairro'];
$cid   = $resultado_busca['cidade'];
$uf    = $resultado_busca['uf'];

```
if($uf == null){
    $retorno2['codigo'] = 1;
$retorno2['resposta'] = "<div class='fimcep'>Nada encontrado</div>"; 

                         header('Content-type: application/json');
                         echo json_encode($retorno2);

}else{
    $retorno2['codigo'] = 0;
$retorno2['resposta'] = "<div class='fimcep'>$log $logr $bai $cid $uf</div>"; 

                         header('Content-type: application/json');
                         echo json_encode($retorno2);

}
```

} else {

```
$retorno2['codigo'] = 1;
$retorno2['resposta'] = "<div class='fimcep'>Nada encontrado</div>"; 

                         header('Content-type: application/json');
                         echo json_encode($retorno2);
```

}

?>